Understanding Open Mapping Theorem for Extensions of Types in Model Theory
I am studying the book "Model Theory" by David Marker, therefore I will use the notations and terminology from this book. I was reading Lemma 6.4.6, that says the following:
Let $T$ be $\omega$-stable. If $A\subseteq B$, $p\in S_n(A)$, $p'\in S_n(B)$, $p'$ is a nonforking extension of $p$, and $p'$ is isolated, then $p$ is isolated.
Proof: We work in $\mathbb{M}^{\mathrm{eq}}$. Let $\phi(\bar{v},\bar{b})$ isolate $p'$. Let $q=\mathrm{tp}(\bar{b}/\mathrm{acl}^{\mathrm{eq}}(A))$. By [Corollary 6.3.21 and] Theorem 6.3.9, there is an $\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{acl}^{\mathrm{eq}}(A)}$-formula $\psi_0(\bar{v})$ such that:
$$\psi_0(\bar{a})\text{ if and only if }\phi(\bar{a},\bar{w})\in\mathrm{tp}(\bar{b}/\mathrm{acl}^{\mathrm{eq}}(A))$$
($\psi_0$ is just $d_q\phi$, where we interchange the roles of the variables). Let $\psi_0(\bar{v})$ be $\psi_1(\bar{v},\bar{\alpha})$ where $\psi_1(\bar{v},\bar{u})$ is an $\mathcal{L}_A$-formula and $\bar{\alpha}\in\mathrm{acl}^{\mathrm{eq}}(A)$. Let $\theta(\bar{u})$ isolate $\mathrm{tp}(\bar{\alpha}/A)$ [by Exercise 4.5.4], and let $\psi(\bar{v})$ be $\exists\bar{u}(\psi_1(\bar{v},\bar{u})\wedge\theta(\bar{u}))$.
We claim that $\psi$ isolates $p$. Suppose that $r\in S_n(A)$ and $\psi\in r$. Then there is $\beta\in\mathrm{acl}^{\mathrm{eq}}(A)$ such that $\theta(\bar{\beta})$ and $r\cup\{\psi_1(\bar{v},\bar{\beta})\}$ is satisfiable [to prove that $\beta\in\mathrm{acl}^{\mathrm{eq}}(A)$, pick the equivalence relation "$\theta(\bar{u})\leftrightarrow\theta(\bar{v})$", that is $A$-definable and has at most $2$ equivalence classes]. Because $\theta$ isolates $\mathrm{tp}(\bar{\alpha}/A)$, $r\cup\{\psi_1(\bar{v},\bar{\alpha})\}$ is satisfiable. Let $r'\in S_n(\mathrm{acl}^{\mathrm{eq}}(A))$ be an extension of $r$ with $\psi_1(\bar{v},\bar{\alpha})\in r'$. By Corollary 6.3.21, $r'$ does not fork over $A$. Let $r''$ be a nonforking extension of $r'$ to $\mathrm{acl}^{\mathrm{eq}}(A)\cup\{\bar{b}\}$ [it exists by Theorem 6.3.2], and let $\bar{a}$ realize $r''$. Because $\bar{a}\perp_{\mathrm{acl}^{\mathrm{eq}}(A)}\bar{b}$, by symmetry [Lemma 6.3.19] $\bar{b}\perp_{\mathrm{acl}^{\mathrm{eq}}(A)}\bar{a}$. Thus $\bar{b}$ realizes the unique nonforking extension of $q$ to $\mathrm{acl}^{\mathrm{eq}}(A)\cup\{\bar{a}\}$ [the extension is unique by Corollary 6.3.13]. But this type has the same definition as $q$ [by Proposition 6.3.8]. Because $\mathbb{M}\models\psi_1(\bar{a},\bar{\alpha})$, $\mathbb{M}\models\phi(\bar{a},\bar{b})$. Because $\phi(\bar{v},\bar{b})$ isolates $p'$, $\bar{a}$ realizes $p'$ and thus $\bar{a}$ realizes $p$ [so that $r=\mathrm{tp}(\bar{a}/A)=p$].
My question is: Where in the proof do we use the hypothesis that the extension $p\subseteq p'$ is nonforking?

I agree with you that there is an argument missing from the proof. Marker has neglected to show that $\psi\in p$, and this is where we need to use that $p'$ is an nonforking extension of $p$. $\DeclareMathOperator{\tp}{tp} \DeclareMathOperator{\acl}{acl} \newcommand{\eq}{eq}$
Here's the missing argument. Let $p''$ be a non-forking extension of $p'$ to $S_n(\acl^{\eq}(A)\cup B)$. Since $p'$ does not fork over $A$, also $p''$ does not fork over $A$. Let $\overline{a}$ realize $p''$. Since $\overline{a}\perp_{A} \acl^{\eq}(A)\cup B$, we have $\overline{a}\perp_{\acl^{\eq}(A)} \overline{b}$, so also $\overline{b}\perp_{\acl^{\eq}(A)} \overline{a}$. Now $\models \phi(\overline{a},\overline{b})$, and $\tp(\overline{b}/\acl^{\eq}(A)\overline{a})$ has the same definition as $\tp(\overline{b}/\acl^{
\eq}(A))$, so $\models \psi_0(\overline{a})$. Thus $\models \psi_1(\overline{a},\overline{\alpha})\land \theta(\overline{\alpha})$, so $\psi\in p''$. Since $\psi$ is a formula over $A$, and $p = p''|_A$, $\psi\in p$.

For a silly example of what can go wrong: In the theory of an infinite set in the language of equality, let $A = \varnothing$, $B = \{b\}$, $p$ the unique type of a single element, and $p'$ the (forking) extension of $p$ isolated by $x = b$. Following Marker's proof, $q$ is again the unique type of the single element $b$ over $\varnothing$. The formula $\phi$ is $x = y$, and the formula $d_q\phi$ is the contradictory formula $\bot$. Thus $\psi_0$ and $\psi$ are both also $\bot$, and clearly $\psi$ does not isolate $p$.

By the way, your parenthetical about why $\beta\in \acl^{\eq}(A)$ is incorrect. It's true that definable equivalence relation $\theta(\overline{u})\leftrightarrow\theta(\overline{v})$ has just two classes and each of these classes is therefore in $\acl^{\eq}(A)$, but $\beta$ is an element of one of these classes, not one of the classes itself.
The real reason $\beta\in \acl^{\eq}(A)$ is that $\beta$ satisfies the formula $\theta$, which is algebraic because it isolates the algebraic type $\tp(\alpha/A)$.
